# SSRS Exclude hidden row values from total

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a column called "Total" in SQL reporting service report.

When generating report I'm hiding some rows accoring to some formula,

But calculating the total that hidden rows values also calculating.
Can I know how to exclude hidden row value from total value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

- Apply the same show/hide logic that you're using to hide rows to the aggregate expression.
- Apply a filter at the table level.

To give an example, say I have some simple data and an associated table:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, say we want to hide all rows with negative values - we can do this by setting the row **Hidden** property as:

```
=IIf(Fields!val.Value > 0, False, True)
```

Which removes the row but doesn't change the total, i.e. what you're seeing:

[image]

We need to apply the same show/hide logic to the `Sum` expression:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!val.Value > 0, Fields!val.Value, Nothing))
```

Now the total looks better:

[image]

Taking a step back, if you want to hide rows and change totals, why not just apply a filter; in the above example this would be:

[image]

Which gives identical results without needing any show/hide logic at the row or total level.

Depending on the complexity of the expression this last option might not be applicable, but seems a bit neater to me if possible.